# How to edit one classes value from another?

Tags: java

I want to take value that one class generates and let another class use it and update it in real time. This is what I did with the class that generates the number:

```
public Integer red(int red){
    this.red = red;
    return red;
}
```

I then called

```
private int red;
```

In the other class I did:

```
int r = gui.red();  //Gui is the name of the original class
```

But it tells me int cant be applied to it. If i set it to 0 it always stays at zero and the other class cant ever change it. How can I make this work right?

Comment: Why are you not returning a primitive int like `public int red()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to edit one classes value from another?

I assume you are asking how to mutate and access the private variables of a class. You can use getters and setters:

For example:

```
class GUI{
    private int red;

    public int getRed(){            //you can name it as red() as you wish
        return red;
    }

    public void setRed(int red){    //you can name is as red(int red)
        this.red = red;
    }
}
```

To access from other class:

```
public class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setRed(val);            //edit gui's red value (val is an int)
        int color = gui.getRed();   //retrieve red from gui object
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so it works, another problem is I have a scrollbar that has a value from 0 to 100 and I need a listener to listen to the changing values. But since I called the private int red outside of the listener the value always stays at zero, and If i call the private int red inside the listener it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any value in the red function. Do that and then use a setter function to set the values and also use a getter to find the latest values.

Answer (score 0):

Make a setter method like Pritam mentioned in the Gui class.

```
public void setRed(Integer red) {
      this.red = red;
}
```

Then you would need to instantiate an object of class Gui.

```
Gui objGui = new Gui();
```

Then use the setter function on that object.

```
objGui.setRed(red);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the red variable as a [private access member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). The scope of this variable will only be within your gui class. Here are two options to change this:

**Adding Setter and Getter Methods**

This is probably the most common way to access private variables in a class. By creating a setter and getter method, you will be able to 'set' the a new value to the red variable and 'get' the new or current red value. An example:

```
public void setRed(int red){
    this.red = red;
}
public int getRed() {
    return red;
}
```

**Change Access Member**

Another option is to simply change the access member from `private int red` to  `public static int red`. However I don't really recommended doing this since the red value will remain the same across all gui class instances. Unless you have a a good reason to use the same variable across, creating setters and getters is the solution.

Comment: Ok so it works, another problem is I have a scrollbar that has a value from 0 to 100 and I need a listener to listen to the changing values. But since I called the private int red outside of the listener the value always stays at zero, and If i call the private int red inside the listener it does not work.

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox It is difficult for us to help without seeing code. Please open a new question on SO so that others with similar situations can be helped too :)